# align text in the middle of a div and align small images in button

Tags: html, css

i want to align the word "or" in the middle of the two middle borders
and i also want to align the small images in my right buttons to the left of their buttons

here is the fiddle link:

http://jsfiddle.net/J82cD/

```
<div class="border"></div>Or<div class="border"></div>
</div>
<div class="social_p">Sign in using your social account</div>
<button type="image" class="social_f"><img src="images/sign-up_facebook.png" align="left">Sign in With my Facebook</button>
<button type="image" class="social_g"><img src="images/sign-up_google.png" align="left">Sign in With my Google</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the "or" word in a `span` and apply the or class to it with this css:

```
.or {
    left: -7px;
    position: relative;
    top: -5px;
}
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/J82cD/3/

Answer (score 0):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/J82cD/5/)

put "Or" in `<span>` like this:

```
<div id="middle">
    <div class="border"></div>
    <span class="center">Or</span>
    <div class="border"></div>
</div>
```

and use this style:

```
span.center {
display: inline-block;
width: 30px;              /*  or something else  */
text-align: center;
margin-left: -15px;       /*  half of width      */
}
```

for your buttons add these styles:

```
button{ position:relative; }
button img {
    position:absolute;
    left:2px;
    top:50%;
    height:20px;        /*  as the height of your icons  */
    margin-top:-10px;   /*  half of height               */
}
```